# Android: Updating Gauge Chart onLocationChanged

Tags: android

**Problem:**  Create a Gauge meter that would display the location accuracy of the device but the challenge here is it operates like a speedometer the data is then changed onLocationChanged

**Tools used:**

1. Numetriclabz readymade Gauge Chart
2. Android Studio

**Algorithm**

Getting the Angle:
   Here i just set 300 m as the lowest accuracy

```
 float getDistance = location.getAccuracy() / 300;
 int mAngle = Math.round(180 - (getDistance * 180));
```

**Code**

```
package com.numetriclabz.gaugemap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts.ChartData;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{

    private static TextView accuracyTxt;
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 0; // in Milliseconds // 5 Seconds
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static Context context;
    private static GChart gauge;
    private static LinearLayout gChart;
    private static List values = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Location location = null;
    private static Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static int timerCount = 2;
    private static  float getDistance;
    private static int mAngle;
    private static ArrayList<GChart> graphView = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        accuracyTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.accuracyTxt);
        context = this;
        gauge = new GChart(context,null);
        gChart = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.gChart);
        values.add(new ChartData(60f));
        values.add(new ChartData(60f));
        values.add(new ChartData(60f));
        gauge.setData(values);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                this
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null && timerCount == 2){
            this.location = location;
            runnable.run();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    public static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                timerCount--;
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);

                if(timerCount == -1){
                    getDistance = location.getAccuracy() / 300;
                    mAngle = Math.round(180 - (getDistance * 180));

                    if(graphView.isEmpty()){
                        gauge.setAngle(mAngle);
                        gauge.invalidate();
                        gauge.refreshDrawableState();
                        gChart.addView(gauge);
                        graphView.add(gauge);
                        gChart.invalidate();
                    }else{
                        gauge.setAngle(mAngle);
                        gauge.invalidate();
                    }

                    accuracyTxt.setText(String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));
                    timerCount = 2;
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

**ISSUE:** the code is working but to often update the view is the issue the pointer won't tick if i update the GaugeChart values it won't update the angle in my gauge chart which is my problem.

**Used idea**  I had used gChart.removeAllViews() method it updated my graph but it is not a user requirement because it should operate like a speedometer that updates values flawless it just only recreates the view.

[Here is a link to my android project file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dn5zsnumt4mvzo4/AADA8yLMeBWuR_D57ZomoqkLa?dl=0)

Hoping for your utmost considerations. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used [Anas Altair SpeedView](https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView) and just modified the code to make it like an Geolocation Accuracy meter actually its a speedometer but i changed the code to meet my requirement.